# How to add span tags to each Chinese and English words in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add span tags to each word of user's input for further manipulation. My attempt so far can only find english words and attach tags， how do I attach span tags to both to english words and Chinese Characters t if user's input has Chinese charecters within.

```
userInput="hello world 一些中文"
var regex = /(<.+?<\/.+?>|\S+)/g;
var result = userInput.replace(regex, function(a) {
    return "<span id=" + (++id) + ">" + a + "</span>";
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this regex instead

```
/[\u00ff-\uffff]|\S+/g
```

It is going to consider anything equal or greater than `\u00ff` a word.

```js
var id = 0;
var userInput="hello world 一些中文"
var regex = /[\u00ff-\uffff]|\S+/g;
var result = userInput.replace(regex, function(a) {
    return `<span id="word${++id}">${a}</span>`;
});
document.getElementById('result').value = result;
```

```css
input { width: 80%; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result" />
```

Comment: If the string contains image tags <img class="blah "src="blah">, is there a way to rule it out ? Sorry this might be out of my original question.

Comment: @zoyb might be better to open a new question and explain in a bit more detail.